# working with Java + RestFB

Tags: java, restfb

So I'm using RestFB Facebook API with JAVA. I want to get a users likes, DOB, education, events, etc.

So i have a main class and within that class I am calling ----

```
_SocialMedia _sm = new _SocialMedia();
```

And within that class I have the following code

```
import com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient;
import com.restfb.FacebookClient;
import com.restfb.Parameter;
import com.restfb.types.User;

public class _SocialMedia_Facebook extends DefaultFacebookClient {
    __CConfig config = new __CConfig();

    public _SocialMedia_Facebook() {
    AccessToken accessToken = obtainAppAccessToken(String.valueOf(config.getFbAppid()), config.getFbAppsecret());
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(String.valueOf(accessToken.getAccessToken()), config.getFbAppsecret(), config.getFbApiversion());
    User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class, Parameter.with("metadata", 1));
    System.out.println(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
}
}
```

The problem I am facing is when i try to execute the program I get the following error message...

```
com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. (code 2500, subcode null)
```

I am completely stuck - any help would be greatly appreciated...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a user access token to fetch the `me` resource, but you fetch an App Access Token.

Comment: Norbert, thanks for pointing that out - I made the correction a couple of days ago, but I'm still unable to get information...am I not using right object - the FacebookClient object?

Comment: try adding `Parameter.with("fields","first_name,last_name")` to fetchObject. I'm not sure what Graph API you are using, but with 2.5 the requested fields are not filled by Facebook until you request them